# finding the first 2 lines with a particular string in a file

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I am trying to read through a file and find the first line that contains the string "ua, ". I want to set that line to be equal to sCurrentLine. After that, I then want to set the next line in the file that contains "ua, " to be equal to sNextLine. Then I will process those line, and after that I want sCurrentLine to be equal to sNextLine and then the loop continues till the end of the file.

This is what I have so far

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{                       
    if (line.contains("ua, "))
{
       sCurrentLine = line;
       //now I don't know what to do
```

Comment: Once you encounter with new line containing `ua, ` previous line will get overwritten with new one. Do you have mechanism for that to save previous line?

Comment: @Smit if thats true then no I do not

Comment: Here you go with @MarounMaroun answer :-}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boolean currentLineSet = false;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{                       
    if (line.contains("ua, "))
    {
       if (!currentLineSet) {
           sCurrentLine = line;
           currentLineSet = true;
       } else {
           sNextLine=line;
       //processing
       sCurrentLine = sNextLine;
       }
    }
```

Comment: I think this works, but I can't figure out why. What is the currentLineSet doing?

Comment: Sorry, the name is a little bit unfortunate - it should rather be "firstLineMet". It is used to deal with the first occurence of the line containing "ua, ", because it should be dealt with "specially" - when you meet the first line, you make no processing and don't set the sNextLine variable. If you have already met the first line, all the next lines can be processed, as shown in the else{} clause.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an `ArrayList` which will contain *Strings*.

```
ArrayList<String> st = new ArrayString<String>();
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{                       
    if (line.contains("ua, "))
    {
       st.add(line);
    }
}
```

Since you don't know the number of lines that will contain the `"ua, "` *String*, you should use an `ArrayList`.

Now you'll have the lines that contains `"ua, "` in the `ArrayList` st.

---

**OP EDIT**

If you want to process two lines, you can save the first line you find with `"ua, "` and then read another line, check if it contains this String:

```
String st1, st2;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{                       
    if (line.contains("ua, "))
    {
       st1 = line;
    }
    if ((line = br.readLine()) != null && line.contains("ua, "))
    {
       st2 = line;
    }
}
```

Of course you can set flags to see whether the first and second lines contained the String.

Comment: Did you post it and then deleted it? I didn't steal anything :D

Comment: I was just kidding.. I was writing and there you posted answer.

Comment: Always happens to me :D I know that feeling ;)

Comment: Heres the thing though, I don't know how many lines will contain `"ua, "` but I want to process 2 lines at a time. So you added sCurrentLine to the arraylist but how would i take the next line with `"ua, "` and process it?

Comment: @MarounMaroun okay so that second if statement will start reading after the first string is saved? Because once I process these 2 strings I then need st1 to equal st2 and continue the pattern

Comment: Then set st1 to st2.. I don't really understand your requirements. Can you clarify it?

Comment: @MarounMaroun my original question is the best way I can explain it

Answer (score 0):

```
int index, iCurrentLine = 1;

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    index++;                     
    if (line.contains("ua, ")) {
        sCurrentLine = line;
        iCurrentLine = index;
    }

}
```

Loop through the file contents again, then make sure that the new index doesn't equal the previous index, then just set `sNextLine = line;`

Comment: How is that different from the OP code, apart from just the formatting?